# Configure Azure VM automatically from marketplace to DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, automation, virtual-machine, devops, cicd

I have deployed a managed application into Azure Marketplace. This application is installed with a Managed Resource Group containing multiple resources, including a Linux VM.

I have a DevOps account where I am setting up pipelines to perform automatic upgrades to my application which gets installed in my VM.

I need to find a way where every new VM (created as part of marketplace application install) is automatically configured with my DevOps pipeline.

[image]

I thought I could just export an ARM template for the VM which would include the 'Continuous Delivery' configuration, and club it to my *mainTemplate.json*(marketplace template). But as I checked, Azure doesn't allow that. Can someone advise on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Automate Virtual Machine Creation in Azure DevOps](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_in/devops/20/h/automate-virtual-machine-creation-in-azure-devops.html), [Configure the blue-green deployment strategy for Azure Linux virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-azure-devops-blue-green-strategy) and [Configure the rolling deployment strategy for Azure Linux virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-devops-azure-pipelines-classic)

Comment: Thanks @DeepDave-MT. Although, I see that it still doesn't answer automatic onboarding of new customer VM's to my pipeline. It instructs to create deployment groups with selected VMs.

My scenario is:
1. Customer installs my managed application from marketplace. 
2. A VM gets built with my application installed under a new managed resource group (accessible through my /publisher's subscription, since it's a managed app). 
3. The VM is automatically connected to the pre-existing DevOps pipeline that I have.